# How to allow user to add columns in interactive grid and set limit?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with columns like : Col01...Col10.

After the 10th column, we need to allow the user to add columns in the grid upto 25.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it can't be done (though, I'd like to know *how* if someone else explains it).

Interactive grid is based on a `SELECT` statement you wrote while designing the page. You can't add another columns to it, can you? Apart from modifying the query itself, of course, and that's not something end users are capable of.

Therefore, create the whole set of columns (25 of them). Hide some of them (from 11 - 25) and save the report as the *default* report. Users will be able to include additional columns using the **Actions** button & "Columns" option, (un)checking the **Displayed** checkbox for each column.

Comment: Another option would be to use a page item to save the amount of additional columns to be shown to the user, make it a select list so the user can also change it and then use server side conditions on the columns to show/hide them.